# Проценты от процента

Tags: c#

Есть 5 значений:

```
{1, 20.0%}
{2, 20.0%}
{3, 20.0%}
{4, 20.0%}
{5, 20.0%}
```

В сумме всегда должно быть 100.0%

Есть переменная в процентах - 41.0%

Нужно прибавить к значению 1, процент переменной от процента значения 1, к значению 1
и высчитать из остальных четырех значений в равной степени, что бы в сумме осталось 100.0%

```
Простой пример:

переменная 20

1 - 50
2 - 50

вычитаем из первого значения переменную и прибавляем к второму значению.

Получаем -

1 - 30
2 - 70
```

Как это сделать ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, double> result = new();

    Dictionary<int, double> dict = new Dictionary<int, double>
    {
        { 0, 15 },
        { 1, 15 },
        { 2, 8  },
        { 3, 10 },
        { 4, 52 }
    };

    double total = 0;

    double x = 41d;
    double t = x / 4d;

    foreach (var d in dict)
    {
        if (d.Key == 0)
        {
            double value = d.Value + (d.Value * x / 100);
            result.Add(0, value);
        }
        if (d.Key == 1)
        {
            double value = d.Value - (d.Value * t / 100);
            result.Add(1, value);
        }
        if (d.Key == 2)
        {
            double value = d.Value - (d.Value * t / 100);
            result.Add(2, value);
        }
        if (d.Key == 3)
        {
            double value = d.Value - (d.Value * t / 100);
            result.Add(3, value);
        }
        if (d.Key == 4)
        {
            double value = d.Value - (d.Value * t / 100);
            result.Add(4, value);
        }
    }

    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        total += r.Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"{r.Key}  {r.Value}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Total - {total}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

```
0  21,15
1  13,4625
2  7,18
3  8,975
4  46,67
Total - 97,4375
```

Comment: А если 1 - 89, 2 - 1, 3 - 10, и надо есделать 3+10, то сколько и откуда надо вычесть? Или 1,2,3,4,5 - 20 и надо сделать 5+2, то сколько и откуда вычесть? из 4 по 0,5 или из первых двух по 1 или из последних двух по 1, или из первого 2, из остальных 0? А так, берете 41%, делите на 4 и вычитаете из каждого по 1/4 части. Готово согласно вашему условию.

Comment: Так я уже пробовал, 100% не выходит в сумме = (

Comment: не видно, где вы пробовали, покажите код, отредактируйте вопрос

Comment: Точней да, оно так работать будет но если только прибавляем к фиксированному значению 20%
Если его изменить на 19 то уже не выходит 100%

Comment: Это похоже на некомпилирующийся код. Чтобы решить эту задачу, надо понять, а сколько должно получиться везде в случаях, когда 1) на цело не делится, быть может надо целыми только числами оперировать? 2) если будет не хватать в какой-то из ячеек 3) если будет не хватать в сумме, то есть берем всё что есть, везде получается 0, а не хватает, уходим в минус или бросаем исключение? И так далее. Условия задачи и пример не покрывают достаточное количество вопросов, чтобы получить верное решение.

Comment: Добавил код.
Не хватать недолжно, потому что мы отнимаем процент а не фиксированное число, в этом и замысел.

Comment: Требуется нормальное описание задачи. (Кроме того,  непонятна цель использования словаря вместо простого массива - но это вторично)

Comment: Задайте вопрос что вам не понятно. словарь использую потому что ключ это постоянное значение, меняются только проценты.

Comment: `прибавить к значению 1, процент переменной от процента значения 1, к значению 1` это я не осилил. И `высчитать из остальных четырех значений в равной степени` - что значит "в равной степени"?

Comment: @MBo  Выше есть готовый код.
Прибавляем к 20%, 41% из 20% то есть 20 * 41 / 100 = 8,2
Вот мы прибавили 8,2% к 20% и теперь в равной степени должны снять с остальных 20% эти самые 8,2% что бы в общем у нас получилось 100%
Это простой пример, там может быть не 20% а 3%, переменная 41% может тоже изменятся.

Answer (score 0):

Вы в последнем комментарии всё правильно написали, осталось только это запрограммировать:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace NsPercents {
    class Percents {
        static void Main() {

            var result = new Dictionary<int, double>();

            var dict = new Dictionary<int, double>
            {
                { 0, 15 },
                { 1, 15 },
                { 2, 8  },
                { 3, 10 },
                { 4, 52 }
            };

            double total = 0;

            double x = 41;
            double t = 0;

            foreach (var d in dict)
            {
                if (d.Key == 0)
                {
                    t = d.Value * x / 100;
                    double value = d.Value + t;
                    result.Add(0, value);
                }
                if (d.Key == 1)
                {
                    double value = d.Value - t / 4;
                    result.Add(1, value);
                }
                if (d.Key == 2)
                {
                    double value = d.Value - t / 4;
                    result.Add(2, value);
                }
                if (d.Key == 3)
                {
                    double value = d.Value - t / 4;
                    result.Add(3, value);
                }
                if (d.Key == 4)
                {
                    double value = d.Value - t / 4;
                    result.Add(4, value);
                }
            }

            foreach (var r in result)
            {
                total += r.Value;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", r.Key, r.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total - {0}", total);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

0  21,15

1  13,4625

2  6,4625

3  8,4625

4  50,4625

Total - 100

И немного улучшить:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace NsPercents {
    class Percents {
        static void Main() {
            var dict = new double[5] { 15, 15, 8, 10, 52 };
            var result = new double[5];
            double x = 41;
            double t = dict[0] * x / 100, total = result[0] = dict[0] + t;
            t /= 4;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) total += result[i] = dict[i] - t;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", i, result[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Total - {0}", total);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно было бы проверять, что в результате доля не становится отрицательной.